# C# Linq with DateTime field

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I want to get data from my sql database, which are all from a specified date or the date from today. Simply all data from today. The field "Zeitsempel" is from type DateTime. I looked for some solutions and found this:

```
var query =
    from z in context.zeichnungs
    where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(z.Zeitstempel) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now)
    select z;
```

The problem I have is, when i use the query data like this

```
foreach (zeichnung zeichnung in query)
{
    if (!zeichnung.Status.Equals("gelöscht"))
    {
        zeichnungInDB = new ZeichnungInDB(zeichnung.Zeichnungsnummer, zeichnung.Index, zeichnung.Volante_Index, zeichnung.Dateiendung, zeichnung.Dokumententyp);
        zeichnungen.Add(zeichnungInDB);
    }
}
```

i get a EntityCommandExecutionException.
Has someone an idea for my problem?

Comment: use DateTime.Today. DateTime.Today represents the current system date with the time part set to 00:00:00 and

DateTime.Now represents the current system date and time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` on an in-memory value produced by `DateTime.Now`. Use [`DateTime.Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
var query =
    from z in context.zeichnungs
    where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(z.Zeitstempel) == DateTime.Today
    select z;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But sadly I got the same error. Have you a other idea, what I can check what the error is?

Comment: @Only3lue Can you try something really simple - select `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(z.Zeitstempel)` values, and convert the result to list to see if this basic step works?

Comment: @Only3lue If you cannot select `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(z.Zeitstempel)` field all by itself, the problem is either with the type or with the content of `Zeitstempel` field in your database.

Comment: Hm, thats weired, because I use othe Linq selects in my program where I read the Zeitstempel field. But I get in there in whole. Don´t know what this is...

Comment: Could it be, because the collation field in the database is empty, that this is a error?

Comment: @Only3lue You can try working around this issue by comparing `Zeitstempel` field to `DateTime.Today` and `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)`, like this: `z.Zeitstempel >= DateTime.Today && z.Zeitstempel < DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)`

Comment: @Only3lue I don't know - given the generalistic kind of error message that you get, I can only guess what is going on.

Comment: Same here :D hm maybe I should kick out the time of the field and only set the date in the database?

Comment: @Only3lue if all you need is the date without the time, storing the date by itself is the best approach.

Comment: Yeah I think so. I guess the problem is really that I can´t crack the DateTime field in Date and Time.

Comment: Okey, so I made an extra date field in the database, now it works fine.

Comment: @Only3lue One thing you may want to double-check is that to use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` you'll need to reference the assembly `System.Data.Entity`. I assume that you are doing it already, but it never hurts to check again.

Comment: Okey I checked it, and added the System.Data.Entity, but unfortunately the error remains.

Answer (score 1):

use DateTime.Today. 
DateTime.Today represents the current system date with the time part set to 00:00:00

and

DateTime.Now represents the current system date and time

to learn more about DateTime: 
[Choosing Between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, TimeSpan, and TimeZoneInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267.aspx)